# Get columns of data with two different date range

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I would like to get the average rating for last 7 days and last 14 days.

I tried using WITH AS to get the data but it's taking way too long to load. Any other way that is better and could reduce the run time?

syntax:

```
WITH last_7_days AS (
SELECT item, rating
FROM sales
WHERE ( 
    rating IS NOT NULL
    AND (entry_date  >= CAST((CAST(now() AS timestamp) + (INTERVAL '-7 day')) AS date) AND entry_date < CAST((CAST(now() AS timestamp) + (INTERVAL '1 day')) AS date))
    )
),

last_14_days AS (
SELECT item, rating
FROM sales
WHERE ( 
    rating IS NOT NULL
    AND (entry_date  >= CAST((CAST(now() AS timestamp) + (INTERVAL '-14 day')) AS date) AND entry_date < CAST((CAST(now() AS timestamp) + (INTERVAL '1 day')) AS date))
    )
)

SELECT last_7_days.item, avg(last_7_days.score) as "avg_last_7_days", avg(last_14_days.rating) as "avg_last_14_days", count(*) AS "count"
FROM last_7_days, last_14_days
WHERE last_7_days.item = last_14_days.item
GROUP BY last_7_days.item
ORDER BY "avg_last_7_days" DESC, last_7_days.item ASC
```

Result should be something like this:

```
item|avg_last_7_days|avg_last_14_days|count|
```

thank you

Comment: Casting on WHERE statements is super inefficient. I'd try to avoid all those casts, and set the variables beforehand on top of the query. Did you try something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT item, 
       AVG(rating) FILTER (WHERE entry_date >= NOW() + interval '-7 day' AND entry_date < NOW() + interval '1 day') AS avg_rating_last_seven_days,
       AVG(rating) FILTER (WHERE entry_date >= NOW() + interval '-14 day' AND entry_date < NOW() + interval '1 day') AS avg_rating_last_fourteen_days
FROM sales
 WHERE rating IS NOT NULL AND 
       (entry_date  >= NOW() + interval '-14 day' AND entry_date < NOW() + interval '1 day')
GROUP BY item;
```

Note:  If you only care about the date, then perhaps you should use `CURRENT_DATE` or even `NOW()::date`.

Comment: super clean, love it! Btw, do you still need to specify in the where clause the date intervals, even though you already did in the conditional aggregations?

Comment: @AleixCC . . . It should make the query a bit faster.  Also, it ensure that items are included only if they have ratings in the past two weeks.

Answer (score 1):

Getting rid of all the casts and aggregating directly on the CTEs should help, try with the following:

```
WITH last_7_days AS (
  SELECT 
    item, 
    AVG(rating) AS avg_rating_last_seven_days
  FROM 
    sales
  WHERE 
    rating IS NOT NULL AND 
    (entry_date  >= NOW() + interval '-7 day' AND entry_date < NOW() + interval '1 day')
  GROUP BY
    1 
),
last_14_days AS (
  SELECT 
    item, 
    AVG(rating) AS avg_rating_last_fourteen_days
  FROM 
    sales
  WHERE
    rating IS NOT NULL AND 
    (entry_date  >= NOW() + interval '-14 day' AND entry_date < NOW() + interval '1 day')
  GROUP BY
    1  
)
SELECT
  lsd.item,
  avg_rating_last_seven_days,
  avg_rating_last_fourteen_days
FROM
  last_7_days AS lsd
INNER JOIN
  last_14_days AS lfd ON lsd.item = lfd.item
```

Let me know in case it helped on improving your current performance!